# Real Time Image processing from a drone

Tags: image-processing, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, ar.drone, dronekit

I have the following products:

```
drone iris+
Pixhawk
```

For my last year project I want to process the image from the drone in real time and to control the drone by the image.

I don't find which product will be the best for me... is it the Raspberry pi or maybe something else that I'm not familiar with.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any embedded linux computer should work.  The Odroid series has more computing power than a raspberry pi, which will be helpful here.  See this article for setup instructions: http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/odroid-via-mavlink/

Comment: Thanks, do you know if I will buy the ODroid will I be able to work with code on windows or it will limit me to linux only?

Comment: linux and android will be easier to use. [Windows 10 for Devices](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot) got release, which is support on Raspberry PI2 and should work on ODroid too, but don't think of it as the Windows you're used to on a desktop/laptop

Answer (score 1):

Regarding software: I would suggest using the OpenCV (computer vision) library for your image processing needs. There's a nice built in function for camera input that interfaces nicely with both Python and C++ programming languages. Depending on your experience writing software, I would recommend python (higher level, possibly slower, portable) or C++ (fighter jet: hard to use, higher ceiling in terms of performance). C++ might be appropriate for the speed necessary to operate a drone. I would check the docs to see if the package serves your needs before diving in.

Regarding hardware: Consider using Arduino to interface with peripheral hardware, but I'm definitely not experienced with this sort of thing.

Have fun!